# Replace unicode characters into a column

Tags: utf-8, google-bigquery, json-query, json-value

I am trying to normalize a column in my table without having an easy way to do it.
I tried to use the NORMALIZE function and other solutions posted here, but nothing works.

I would like to get a text normalized from the table like "C\u00f3mo funciona" => "Cómo funciona".

[image: Example of a row in my table]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was that before saving the data, I made a json_encode that encodes all the data before it can be writted. I only use [JSON_QUERY](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/json_functions#json_query) and [JSON_VALUE](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/json_functions#json_value) functions of BigQuery to recover and decode the special characters.